# HLSL tex2d sampler seemingly using inconsistent rounding; why?

Tags: rounding, hlsl

I have code that needs to render regions of my object differently depending on their location. I am trying to use a colour map to define these regions.

The problem is when I sample from my colour map, I get collisions. Ie, two regions with different colours in the colourmap get the same value returned from the sampler.

I've tried various formats of my colour map. I set the colours for each region to be "5" apart in each case;

- **Indexed colour**
- **RGB, RGBA**: region 1 will have RGB 5%,5%,5%. region 2 will have RGB 10%,10%,10% and so on.
- **HSV Greyscale**: region 1 will have HSV 0,0,5%. region 2 will have HSV 0,0,10% and so on.

(Values selected in The Gimp)

The tex2D sampler returns a value [0..1].

[ I then intend to derive an int array index from region. Code to do with that is unrelated, so has been removed from the question ]

```
float region = tex2D(gColourmapSampler,In.UV).x;
```

Sampling the "5%" colour gave a "region" of 0.05098 in hlsl.
From this I assume the 5% represents 5/100*255, or 12.75, which is rounded to 13 when stored in the texture. (Reasoning: 0.05098 * 255 ~= 13)

By this logic, the 50% should be stored as 127.5. 
Sampled, I get 0.50196 which implies it was stored as 128.

the 70% should be stored as 178.5. 
Sampled, I get 0.698039, which implies it was stored as 178.

**What rounding is going on here**? 
(127.5 becomes 128, 178.5 becomes 178 ?!)

Edit: OK,
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankers_rounding#Round_half_to_even
Apparently this is "banker's rounding". I have no idea why this is being used, but it solves my problem. Apparently, it's a Gimp issue.

---

I am using Shader Model 2 and FX Composer. This is my sampler declaration;

```
//Colour map
texture gColourmapTexture <
    string ResourceName = "Globe_Colourmap_Regions_Greyscale.png";
    string ResourceType = "2D";
>;
sampler2D gColourmapSampler : register(s1) = sampler_state {
Texture = <gColourmapTexture>;
#if DIRECT3D_VERSION >= 0xa00
    Filter = MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
#else /* DIRECT3D_VERSION < 0xa00 */
    MinFilter = Linear;
    MipFilter = Linear;
    MagFilter = Linear;
#endif /* DIRECT3D_VERSION */
    AddressU = Clamp; 
    AddressV = Clamp;
};
```

Comment: Rounding happens in the image editor. The 8b texture is not able to represent anything but integers. You cannot store 178.5 in the texture, you need to store 178 or 179, meaning 178/255 or 179/255.

Shaders do not use any rounding to integer. Their rounding to float precision is unlikely to hit you here.

Comment: Haha, ofc. It must be related to how gimp saves values in textures then. Nothing to do with HLSL at all :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIMP uses [banker's rounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bankers_rounding#Round_half_to_even). Apparently.

This threw out my code to derive region indicies.

Answer (score 1):

I never used HLSL, but I did use GLSL a while back (and I must admit it's terribly far in my head).

One issue I had with textures is that 0 is not the first pixel. 1 is not the second one. 0 is the edge of the texture and 1 is the right edge of the first pixel. The values get interpolated automatically and that can cause serious trouble if what you need is precision like when applying a lookup table rather than applying a normal texture. You need to aim for the middle of the pixel, so asking for [0.5,0.5], [1.5,0.5] rather than [0,0], [1, 0] and so on.

At least, that's the way it was in GLSL.

Comment: Aye, the interpolation does cause problems on region borders (I get a seam as the lookup value is invalid, so no colour) but that's not the same as this problem I don't think. I'm hoping to solve the seam issue by disabling bilinear filtering in the sampler definition. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Beware: region in levels[region] is rounded down. When you see 5 % in your image editor, the actual value in the texture 8b representation is 5/100*255 = 12.75, which may be either 12 or 13. If it is 12, the rounding down will hit you. If you want rounding to nearest, you need to change this to levels[region+0.5].

Another similar thing (already written by Louis-Philippe) which might hit you is texture coordinates rounding rules. You always need to hit a spot in the texel so that you are not in between of two texels, otherwise the result is ill-defined (you may get any of two randomly) and some of your source texels may disapper while other duplicate. Those rules are different for bilinar and point sampling, you may need to add half of texel size when sampling to compensate for this.

Comment: "You always need to hit a spot in the texel so that you are not in between of two texels". A spot in the texture*? It's likely texels will indeed span region boundaries in my texture. I think this causes my seam bug. However I'm getting whole regions with the same region value. These are however adjacent, so a rounding problem is likely. I tried floor-ing/ceil-ing the index, but with no joy. I shall investigate further. Ty for your suggestion.

Comment: I have used following debugging technique in past: instead of returning the real value, I return some value I want to inspect and check if it is what I expect it to be. In your case, can you try returning region from the shader and check if it what you want it to be?

Comment: Using brute force (if region > foo draw blue, else if region > bob draw green) I've determined the values of region. This is indeed where the consistency lies, ty. I've simplified the question. +1 for pointing me in the right direction. Problem remains unsolved though.